# Change tab bar button sequence from storyboard

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I try to change tab bar button sequence.

Right now sequence of tab bar is

1. Notification
2. Message
3. Friend
4. My fav.
5. Home

I want sequence of tab bar

1. Home
2. Message
3. Friend
4. My fav.
5. Notification

Move Home to first button

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select the TabBarIcon and drag and put wherever you want to put it like this, No need to remove all relationships.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just select the Tab you want to move any other position in TabbarController in Storyboard.

It will Work!!!